# API for Login information

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-admin-settings-api, google-admin-audit-api

I have had a call logged with Google to get all logon/logoff events as there has been an incident in our school where we suspect another user has logged on with the credentials of another user in school and posted unsavoury information.  I want to track back through all events to see where this user potentially logged on and what time.  Google said that they have limited information and what I have access to does not match up with what Google can see and vice versa. And I would need to post here for Google to create me an API.  Could this be carried out please?

Comment: *And I would need to post here for Google to create me an API* ... whoever told you that, simply **lied** to you. End of story. This is a community that helps *you* with your programming problems. Your request is way too broad for this community, and **nobody** here can make Google create an API for you.

Comment: And honestly: who upvoted *this* question?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the Reports API that has the [Login Activity Report](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/manage-audit-login) of all your account's users.

It has an API that retrieve G Suite login events for a domain and some instances, retrieve G Suite login events by event name such as suspicious successful logins.